# Angular formBuilder create control with ValidatorFn from jsonfconfig string

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

**Here you can find the project in stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-dynamic

I'm trying to create a Reactive form from a JSON configuration like this:

```js
    export const jsonConfigForm = {
      title: "Dynamic form test",
      className: "d-form",
      fields: [
        {
          name: "Email",
          type: "email",
          validators: ["Validator.required", "Validator.minLength(5)"],
          customValidator: [],
          className: "d-form__email",
          value: "info@prova.it",
        },
        {
          name: "Autocomplete",
          type: "autocomplete",
          options: [
            { label: "Select one", value: "" },
            { label: "Uno", value: "uno" },
            { label: "Due", value: "due" },
            { label: "Tre", value: "tre" },
          ],
          validators: ["required"],
          customValidator: [],
          className: "d-form__email",
          value: "uno",
        },
      ],
    };
```

When I try to create a control from fields config the validators array string throws an error.
This is my code:

```js
    export interface FieldConfig {
      name: string;
      type: string;
      options?: Array<OptionsConfig>;
      validators?: Array<ValidatorFn>;
      customValidator?: Array<string>;
      className?: string;
      value?: any;
    }
    
    get formFields(): Array<FieldConfig> {
        return this.jsonExist && this.jsonConfig.fields;
      }
    formGroupContainer: FormGroup = this.fb.group({});
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formFields?.forEach((field: FieldConfig) => {
          this.formGroupContainer.addControl(
            field.name,
            this.fb.control(field.value, field.validators)
          );
        });
      }
```

This is the error:

```
    Types of property 'fields' are incompatible.
        Type '({ name: string; type: string; validators: string[]; customValidator: any[]; className: string; value: string; options?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; options: { label: string; value: string; }[]; validators: string[]; customValidator: any[]; className: string; value: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'FieldConfig[]'.
          Type '{ name: string; type: string; validators: string[]; customValidator: any[]; className: string; value: string; options?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; options: { label: string; value: string; }[]; validators: string[]; customValidator: any[]; className: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FieldConfig'.
            Type '{ name: string; type: string; validators: string[]; customValidator: any[]; className: string; value: string; options?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'FieldConfig'.
              Types of property 'validators' are incompatible.
                Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
                  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
    
    this.jsonConfig = jsonConfigForm;
```

How can I create a `FormControl` with validators from `jsonConfig` file using `FormBuilder`?

**Here you can find the project in stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-dynamic

Comment: Provide error reproduction on stackblitz - this way you will get much better help. Though it seems that the exception is thrown from the place where you map your `jsonConfigForm` to `this.jsonConfig`. And you don't provide that code at all, so there's no way for us to know what's wrong.

Comment: Done, you can find here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-dynamic

Comment: Anyone can answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

`FormControl` constructor (or `this.fb.control()`, which basically is a helper method calling FormControl constructor) expects either ValidatorFn or ValidatorFn[] as second parameter. Looking at your interface, you're providing strings - hence  it's throwing a compile error. It's a type mismatch. So, you need to translate those into real validator functions matching the ValidatorFn signature.

I've provided a simple implementation in a forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-dynamic-avyjqq).

Note the `this.fb.control(field.value, this.parseValidators(field.validators))` and related `private parseValidators(validatorStrings: string[]): ValidatorFn[]` in your `FormsComponent`. It's a sample implementation that only handles one validator, but should get you started on how it could work.

Of course this is a bit dirty solution - likely you will want it solved in a different manner (e.g. FieldConfig being class instead of interface with ValidatorFn[] as validators and them being parsed in constructor).

Comment: thank you very much, some of your suggestions are no so clear for me (es: transform interface in class) but I will study yours solutons.

Comment: I check in https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-dynamic-avyjqq but it seems that doesn't work.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that - seems that the latest changes weren't saved when I closed the project. I've re-written it, check again :)

Comment: Thank you very much, you are very kind!